# Concatenation of lines

Tags: awk, sed

I need to join every other line in a file with the line after it.

```
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
9, 10
11, 12
```

The output should be like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

I have used `awk '{getline b;printf("%s,%s\n",$0,b)}' file`.  However, the output is:

```
1, 2
,3, 4
5, 6
,7, 8
9, 10
,11, 12
```

I wonder how each line can be concatenated with the line after it.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your `file` has DOS/Windows line-endings?

Comment: @John1024 it was the carriage return character which was causing the trouble. When I replaced \r\n with , everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Because Unix tools do not expect `\r`, it often causes trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
sed 'N;s/\n/, /' file
```

This N appends the next line and s command substitutes the newline with a comma and space.

The output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{a=$0; getline; print a", "$0}' file
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

#### How it works

- `a=$0`

  This saves the current line in variable `a`.
- `getline`

  This reads the next line into `$0`.
- `print a", "$0`

  This prints them both side by side with a comma between them.

Comment: mmm I don't really like using `getline` here, it can be avoided by for example using a different ORS. Check my answer if you feel like to

Answer (score 1):

The classical and idiomatic way to do it with `awk` is like follows:

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%2?", ":RS' file
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

This is based on an example in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) and works as follows:

- `ORS=NR%2?", ":RS` set the Output Record Separator to either ", " or new line, depending on which line are we considering:

  - if the Number of Record is odd, then set it to ", ".
  - otherwise, to RS, which default to the new line.

Comment: @ fedorqui :  why are you doing math ? see my answer

Answer (score 0):

the below will also do the trick
 `paste -s -d ',\n'` file

Answer (score 0):

don't do math when none is called for :

```
{m,g}awk 'ORS = RS<ORS ? RS :", "' FS='^$'

1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```